# Bluestacks ask Google Play Service eventhough it was installed

Tags: google-account, google-play-services, bluestacks

I'm trying to play Clash of Clans on my Windows 8 PC with Bluestacks app player. Installation was successful and after launching the game and click on Sign-in to Google+, it said Google Play Service is required. I checked the settings->app and it was already installed. I tried to remove and reinstall but still doesn't work. I can't also sign-in to Google account in setting->accounts. Please give me some advice. Thanks.